# Does disabing wuauserv service affect installation of updates?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, services

I want to manually control the launch the Windows Update service on a Windows 10 Home laptop because it runs too frequently, causing high CPU and draining the battery.

The idea is that the the service will be disabled and the user will launch Windows Updates on demand and then once the service has started and it is under way, set the service *immediately* to Disabled again. This should ensure that once updates are applied, Windows Update will not launch again by itself.

My question is, considering some updates need to reboot the system to complete their installation, would disabling the service in this way cause issues with these updates?

Alternatively, and unfortunately more complicated, is to

- Set Windows Update service to its own svchost.exe process
- Launch the service & Check for updates
- Monitor CPU usage and disable once found it has settled down.

My plan is for the user to launch the update when they go to sleep and hopefully when they wake, the updates will have been done and the service will be disabled.

---

EDIT:

What I have done so far is to create two VBS scripts. One to stop and disable the service. It runs automatically at logon with elevated privileges through the Task Scheduler.

The second script enables the service and starts it. Then the GUI is presented to the user to click "Check for Updates". This way they can keep an eye on it. I will have her launch the second script once a week, probably weekends when she goes to sleep. Reboots should occur automatically.

Comment: You could make a bat file and set it to run with admin priveledges and uac disabled at user logon after boot using task scheduler. the 2 Commands in the bat file would be "sc config wuauserv start= disabled" and "sc stop wuauserv" spaces are important.

Comment: See this post to see how to run a task from the startup folder....http://superuser.com/questions/1070619/how-to-grant-elevated-privileges-to-a-windows-10-startup-shortcut

Comment: No problem, once the updates are downloaded and start to install you can stop the windows update service.

Comment: @Moab Scripting is not a problem. I've already got part of it done in VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can do this easily on Home edition, since there is no GPO support.

The only option to prevent from auto restarting after installing update, you can configure this to schedule restart:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2953010/windows/how-to-schedule-your-windows-10-updates.html